# vba macro copies all charts twice instead of once

Tags: excel, vba

This vba macro copies all charts to a temp sheet, it is working well however it seems to copy every chart twice instead of once. How can I modify the code so that it doesn't duplicate each chart?

```
Sub macro1()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim adH As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
Dim sht As Worksheet, shtSource As Worksheet, wk As Worksheet
'===================================================================
'===================================================================
Sheets.Add After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "ALL"
Set sht = ActiveSheet
'===================================================================
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'===================================================================
'Excluding fixed tab, copying all charts from all tabs to ALL
For Each wk In Worksheets
    If wk.Name <> "fixed" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            j = wk.ChartObjects.Count
                For i = 1 To j
                    wk.ChartObjects(i).Activate
                    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
                    sht.Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    sht.Range("A" & 1 + i & "").Select
                 Next i
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through each worksheet, including the new worksheet to which you just added charts. This is the cause of your duplication. You'll need to exclude the newly added worksheet from your loop...

```
For Each wk In Worksheets
    If wk.Name <> "fixed" and wk.Name <> "ALL" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            j = wk.ChartObjects.Count
                For i = 1 To j
                    wk.ChartObjects(i).Activate
                    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
                    sht.Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    sht.Range("A" & 1 + i & "").Select
                 Next i
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next
```